# Generic method How can I define with my class type?

Tags: java, generics, syntax-error

I want to use the guava library implemented with generic type.
Now in my code I have to use them, but I am not familiar of using generic method.

This is the method description from the API :

`public static <N> Set<N> reachableNodes(Graph<N> graph, N node)`

This methods returns set of nodes that is reachable from one node in the graph.

In my project **I have graph class as "Graph" and node class as 'Node**" and I want to substitute with the method with my classes. I have tried like this and I get error :

```
Set<Node> reachableNodes = new HashSet<>();
reachableNodes= Graphs.<Graph, Node>reachableNodes(g, n);
```

Here g is Graph class type and n is Node type.

The error says "Incorrect number of type arguments for generic method reachableNodes(Graph, N) of type Graphs; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Graph, Node>".

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is more about answers to specific problems and not for personal tutorials, I would recommend looking maybe here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html to get an overview of generics.

Comment: I do not know after I read that that's why I questioned here, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

### Type variables

the first `<N>` in `public <N> Set<N> reachableNode` declares it. It's like the `x` in `void foo(int x)`: It decrees that it exists, it doesn't define what it is, or use it. All other usages are using it. As the name suggests, the 'value' of a type variable is a type (like `int`, `Object`, or `Map<List<? extends String>, ? super Number>`), just like the 'value' of `int x` is an integer.

A type variable is 'set' for any given invocation of the method. So, whenever you invoke this method, `N` is, well, something. Every invocation gets to set it, just like how a method `void foo(int x)` gets its own x. `foo(5)`? Then x is 5. `foo(10)`? Then x is 10.

### Inference

Ordinarily, java will attempt to automatically figure out what value is appropriate for a given type variable. There needs to be some context surrounding your invocation (either a parameter, or how you use it, or both) for java to do this. In this case, there is ample support: The `reachableNodes` method returns a `Set<N>`, and you assign the result of calling it to a variable of type `Set<Node>`: Java is smart enough to figure out that if we go: `N = Node`, that it then 'works'. The same rule applies, presumably, to your usage of your variable `n` (which is no doubt of type Node), as well as `g` (which is presumably of type `Graph<Node>`. All 3 say the same thing: If N is Node, then it works.

So java will just do that, and the right answer is to just write:

```
reachableNodes = Graphs.reachableNodes(g, n);
```

Absolutely no need to write the 'value' for N out explicitly here.

### Manually specifying type vars

I can't stress enough how idiomatic java means you should not specify these things unless there is no other way. However, it *is* possible to explicitly state what each type variable is supposed to be. If you use this, each and every type variable of that method needs to be spelled out. The syntax is `something.<typearg1, typearg2>methodName(params);`, where something needs to be present, can be `this` if you want. Your `reachableNodes` method has 1 type argument (that `<N>`, the very first occurrence of it, that declares it, the rest is using it), so 1 thing needs to be in those `<>`, you have 2 things, and **that is why the compiler says your code is erroneous**. Just `Graphs.<Node>reachableNodes(g, n)` does the job, but, the `<Node>` bit is superfluous. The compiler can figure it out on its own, no need for you to write it out.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the helpful answer! I think i can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you are trying to recreate these methods from the Guava library using your own Graph and Node classes, in which case you simply need to reuse this method declaration and implement it while ensuring you're importing your Graph and Node classes rather than the library's.

```
public static <N> Set<N> reachableNodes(Graph<N> graph, N node) {
    // your implementation...
}
```

This code

```
Set<Node> reachableNodes = new HashSet<>();
reachableNodes= Graphs.<Graph, Node>reachableNodes(g, n);
```

1. instantiates a new HashSet<Node> assigned to reachableNodes
2. reassigns reachableNodes to an invalid method declaration?

I'm not sure if the intention was this, but it would be invalid regardless.

```
Set<Node> Graphs.<Graph, Node> reachableNodes(g, n);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. To be more specific, I do not want to recreate(edit the code ) but I want to use the method that is already defined without changing anything. But if I want to use it, should I recreate it? I thought my problem is to use my class types in the generics.

Comment: @user15348714 If you simply want to use the library, you don't need to recreate anything. Simply import the library's existing Graph and Node classes into your file and create a new graph using Graph<NODECLASS> graph = new Graph<>(); Replace NODECLASS with whatever object class you want to use to represent the nodes - Integer as an example. You populate the graph and can then call Graphs.reachableNodes(graph, node) with whichever node you've stored as a variable.

I highly recommend you read on how generics work in the Oracle tutorials.